# Not able to create sFTP connector in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying out the Logic App in Azure. I created the logic App and then added the sFTP connector. I entered the Server Address,server port and changed the "Accept Any SSH Server HostKey" to true. I'm leaving the "SSH Server HostKey", Root Folder and "Encrypt Cipher" fields as blank since they are optional and I don't have that information. See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/app-service-logic-connector-sftp/

With all that above information entered I'm not able to save the logic app.A message "Incomplete Changes You have added or edited 'sftpconnector' but have not completed your changes. Click OK to discard your changes." id displayed when I click on Save.

Any help on adding the sFTP connector to the logic will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the [screenshot](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/app-service-logic-connector-sftp/), You need to click "OK" after modifying the Package Settings. Make sure you have selected an appropriate App Service Plan too.

Comment: Trust me it was not working. The Ok and Create button were greyed out. But it seems to be working now. Created the connector first from the marketplace and then added to the logic app. Thank you.